# Software to solve basic set equations (in algebra of sets)?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, math-software, symbolic-computation

What symbolic math software is able to solve basic set equations? E.g.

$X \setminus A = C \setminus X $, for $X$

Comment: [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org) deals with sets, see [this chapter from its Tutorial](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/tut/chap3.html#X83BE0C20875DD285). Regarding $X \setminus A = C \setminus X $, perhaps this could be solved analytically?

Comment: I'm inspired by Maxima's symbolic solvers for equations on complex numbers, so I think there must be symbolic solvers for equations on sets. Sure, this equation is easy solvable by hand.